# How do I improve this piece of code to be error free

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code to solve the liquid drop model in nuclear physics (I know this is not relevant to my query but I need to type some text in order for me to submit the question I am really sorry if I am being rude this way I just need help to solve this please)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#importing the excel sheet with elements, mass and atomic number
x=pd.read_excel('Elements.xlsx')
#converting atomic number column to a list
Z=x['Z'].tolist()
#converting mass column to another list
A=x['A'].tolist()
#converting number of neutrons to another list
N=x['N'].tolist()
#defining a function as the binding energy per nucleon eqn according to liquid drop model
#different energies per nucleon are listed below:
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5=14.1,13,0.595,19.0,33.5
i=0
Ev=a1 #volume energy per nucleon
Es=-a2/((A[i])**(1/3) #surface energy per nucleon
Eo=-a3*Z[i]*(Z[i]-1)/((A[i])**(4/3)) #coloumb energy per nucleon
Ea=-a4*((A[i]-2*Z[i])**2)/((A[i])**2) #asymmetry energy per nucleon
Ep=a5/(A[i])**(7/4) #pairing energy per nucleon

def y(i):
    if Z[i]%2==0 and N[i]%2==0:
        return Ev+Es+Eo+Ea+Ep
    elif Z[i]%2!=0 and N[i]!=0:
        return Ev+Es+Eo+Ea
    else:
        return Ev+Es+Eo+Ea-Ep
```

I am getting this error:

```
 Eo=-a3*Z[i]*(Z[i]-1)/((A[i])**(4/3)) #coloumb energy per nucleon
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea what to fix here. Please help.

Comment: The line above you have a unbalanced parentheses. Should probably be `Es=-a2/((A[i])**(1/3))`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a bracket here:

```
Es=-a2/((A[i])**(1/3)) #<--Here: surface energy per nucleon
```

The best piece of advice for you would be:

1. Comment out the problematic piece of code
2. Insert stub value for Eo (such as Eo = 0)
3. The cause for such a bug would be obvious
4. If still not obvious, comment out the code on top/bottom, piece by piece, then the cause for such a bug would be even more obvious